# CPropertySheet: How to get the child page from OnDrawItem

Tags: winapi, mfc

I've added some code as found here [Big problems with MFC/WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977689/big-problems-with-mfc-winapi) to colour tab titles the same as the reset of the dialog, which works, but unfortunately all the tabs end up with the same name. This doesn't surprise me all that much as GetCurSel() is used to grab the text to use, and only one tab can currently be selected, but I'm struggling to see how you access the correct tab index from OnDrawItem().

I've googled and had a look on MSDN but don't see how anything passed to OnDrawItem lets you know which tab is currently being drawn, rather all the examples I've seen assume you're only interested in the one currently selected. All I want to do is something along the lines of GetWindowText() on the child window and redraw with that. I'm also unsure of the parent/child/sibling relationship between the sheet, tab control and page - it depends who you listen to.

I should probably add that I'm also unsure why all the tabs are redrawn when I select one. I don't know if this is normal or something specific to this implementation (that's something I'm looking at, but like seemingly everything else in this code base it's multiply inherited several times over ...).

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry, I now realise lpDrawItemStruct->itemID holds the tab index so I can get a handle to the tab using that.